# Postman unable to show UI - windows native app

Tags: postman

When I click on Postman native windows app to open it shows the following UI but does not load.

[image: Postman does not load]

[image: UI not showing]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the installed app icon and enter the following in Target

C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Postman\Update.exe --processStart "Postman.exe" **--process-start-args="--disable-gpu"**

[image: How to do]

[Click here to read more about the issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4594)

Comment: I'm running in a VM (who isn't??), and I needed to do this in order to see the GUI.

Comment: I'm not running it in a VM but you have to do it either ways to see the GUI.